# How do I Prevent combobox value from changing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, combobox

Say, I've got a combo box with the following declaration:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbBaseClass" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableBaseClasses}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding InheritGuid, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    Style="{DynamicResource ContentClassComboBox}" />
```

When user changes value, in some circumstances, I'm asking him, whether he really want to do that. When he chooses "no", I'm not changing value in underlying viewmodel. But the value in ComboBox changes anyway (despite it's now not in sync with viewmodel).

Property in ViewModel is declared as following:

```
    public ContentClassInfo InheritGuid {

        get {

            var info = //Get data
            return info;
        }
        set
        {
            SetInheritGuid(value);
        }
    }
```

---

**Edit:** Source of SetInheritGuid:

```
private void SetInheritGuid(ContentClassInfo value)
{
    // ...
    // Irrelevant part
    // ...

    if (removedInheritedProps.Count > 0)
    {
        if (
            editorDispatcher.Show(
                "(...) Are you sure?",
                button: MessageBoxButton.YesNo, icon: MessageBoxImage.Warning) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            // ...
            // Prepare for change
            // ...
        }
        else
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("InheritGuid");
            return;
        }
    }

    contentClass.InheritGuid.Value = value.ContentClass;
    OnPropertyChanged("InheritGuid");

    // ...
    // Irrelevant
    // ...
}
```

---

**Edit:** [Proof-of-concept application](http://www.spook.freshsite.pl/Temporary/BindingProblem.zip)

1. Choose any value and answer "Yes" - value will be changed
2. Choose any other value and answer "No" - value will be changed anyway

How may I prevent the value of ComboBox from changing?

Comment: well it sounds simple - you ask a question, if ans I NO, do not let setter work, I cant understand much from your code, please add more bits to make it clearer

Comment: just edited to findout there is  combobox code..

Comment: you must save Dim k as Integer = combobox.selectedItem before. If choose "no" then combobox.selectedIndex = k, or somethig similar in view.

Comment: what is setInheritGuid doing ?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @Muds It asks user, whether to change value or not and acts accordingly to his choice. The point is, that if user chooses not to make change, value of `InheritGuid` will be exactly the same as it were before the change.

Comment: do you INotify after ?

Comment: @Muds I've edited my post to include some more source code.

Comment: this looks ok now thing remains is -- var info = //Get data
check if that's alright ?

Comment: @Muds It is. I've debugged the flow and it goes like: ComboBox change -> setter -> SetInheritGuid -> **getter** (as an effect of `INotify...`) -> ComboBox sets value to new one instead leaving the old one

Comment: and getter returns old value ?

Comment: @Muds I've included a simple proof-of-concept application. You can check simply by yourself.

Comment: @XAMIMAX Take a look at the proof-of-concept app. I'm already doing that.

Comment: Related information - two last posts: https://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2009/05/27/wpf-4-0-data-binding-change-great-feature/

Comment: @XAMIMAX I tried that, but doing so causes the setter to be run again and again until I choose the other option. Could you post an answer with fixed code?

Comment: Ignore my propositions I am looking into the issue more closely, reason why it worked for me is because when I was testing it the combobox initially didn't have selected value, so when I selected value and then selected no it would work, as soon as you select value with yes and then try no it loops endlessly. I'll come back to you when I have some results.